# Get the default raspberry pi internet disconnection event

Tags: raspbian, python, internet

I'm working on a python script running on a script, which would upload some files to the server. Probably, this needs internet connectivity to be turned on. I'm seeing a log `pi@raspberrypi dhcpd[5] carrier lost` in `/var/log/syslog` when the internet lost and `carrier acquired`, when internet connection available. Is there a way to get this as an event in my python program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't tell us if you'd tried anything, and so I'll assume that you haven't. If that's the case, I'd suggest you take a look at [this answer from Stack Overflow SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419888/reading-from-a-frequently-updated-file). In a nutshell, it suggests that you use [David Beazley's Generator Tricks for Python](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/), but the code is actually on [Beazley's GitHub page](https://github.com/dabeaz/generators). I think the specific code you'll need is [this one](https://github.com/dabeaz/generators#part-5--processing-infinite-data)

All of this for the price of an [Internet search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=reading+log+file+updates+Python&t=ffnt&ia=web)  :)

Try this; let us know if you have any RPi-related issues.